# Squid: timeout after acl file load

Tags: proxy, squid, timeout

I have installed Squid 3.5.23 like proxy on my server.

I have downloaded a huge file (15MB) with domains to block and I have added this file to my squid.conf throught *acl blocksites url_regex "file"* (like many other time in many other conifiguration). After that I reload my squid configuration with */etc/init.d/squid reload" but this operation goes to timeout (with *systemctl status squid.service* i get *squid.service: Reload operation timed out. Killing reload process.*

I think that the problem is related to the huge size of the file.

Anybody know a way to increment timeout size, or another way to load that file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved using squidguard with squid!